# Do we still need to worry about long fat pipes?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp

I am trying to settle a controversy we have at work.

A decade ago TCP used to have really bad performance over long fat pipes, i.e., network paths that feature high bandwidth-delay product. Sysadmins used to tune the TCP stack with some "golden" sysctl values that would magically increase iperf transfer rates to Gbps.

In the meantime, many things have happened. Looking at Linux, it added support for TCP timestamps, buffer auto-tuning, RTT measurement, CUBIC congestion control, SACK, to name a few that I am aware of.

Do we still need to tune the TCP stack for long fat pipes or do today's users get Gbps transfer rates out-of-the-box?

Comment: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on **actual problems that you face.**" from [help/dont-ask]

Comment: @DavidPostill Wasting time is a problem for me. I want to know if I should waste time on tuning the TCP stack or if it is auto-tuning itself sufficiently for today's high-speed high-latency network. Is there a particular point I should elaborate in my question?

Answer (score 2):

No need anymore, unless it's REALLY long (like satellite endpoints). This is all handled dynamically and effectively. In most cases all you might need is to use a large MTU for storage networks, etc.

Comment: Can you point me to some supporting evidence, like a blog post, scientific article, report, etc.?

Comment: I can't for this, because you haven't presented a case that requires tuning. Your question reads as "do we need to tune TCP settings for long gigabit pipes?" and the answer is "that's handled dynamically, so typically no." The default TCP stack on modern distributions is optimized for gigabit ethernet. As a general rule of TCP tuning, you should only tune if you *ran into a problem*. Worrying about tuning beforehand is pointless, and applying golden rules for it manually ahead of time would be foolish (as it would more likely degrade performance than anything else).

Comment: Agree. We only achieved 105Mbps (notice the weird 5) over a WAN, with both ends Gigabit. I was wondering if we should investigate a possible cap somewhere in the WAN or if this is (still) a typical TCP tuning problem. Ideally I would like to read a report with statements such as "for 1Gbps/100ms auto-tuning is sufficient, for 10Gbps/100ms you need to increase this and that, 40Gbps/100ms is currently not handled well by TCP."